# Complex object is coming as NULL for HttpPut in ASP.Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am building a webapi using Asp.Net Core 2.2. One of my controllers has a Put method to update an entity. The problem is, the complex object I pass from postman rest client is always null.

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("{searchPatternId:long}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(long searchPatternId, [FromBody]SearchPattern searchPattern)
{
        try
        {
            if (searchPattern == null) return BadRequest();

            return Ok(await _searchPatternService.PutAsync(searchPattern));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await _errorLogService.Log(e);
            return StatusCode(500);
        }
}
```

SearchPattern class:

```
[Table("search_pattern", Schema = "abc")]
public class SearchPattern
{
    [Key]
    public long SearchPatternId { get; set; }
    public string Pattern { get; set; }
    public long PatternHash { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public long TotalRecordsFound { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int LastSearchedPage { get; set; }
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Postman request:

[image]

This is what I have tried so far:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("{searchPatternId:long}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromRoute]long searchPatternId, [FromBody]SearchPattern searchPattern)

[HttpPut("{searchPatternId:long}")]    
public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromRoute]long searchPatternId, [FromBody]SearchPattern searchPattern)

[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromBody]SearchPattern searchPattern)
```

Debugging Output:

[image]

Comment: No! There is nothing like that! `[HttpPut]
[Route("{searchPatternId:long}")]` and `[HttpPut("{searchPatternId:long}")]` are simultaneous.

Comment: can you share your complex object as text, not on the picture? I want to test otherwise your code is working for me.

Comment: @Amir Assuming there aren't missing members in the JSON, that the class is public and all its members are public properties, this works fine

Comment: do you other put method on that controller?

Comment: I have tested using your code and it is working. There might be other issues. https://imgur.com/1CuPzos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `searchPattern` parameter is set to `null` because model binder got at least one invalid value for model property. In your case it's obvious that `updateDate` is mapped to `DateTime` type but specified value has invalid format

```
2019-03-27T01:20:00 PM
```

`PM` part is invalid here, just remove it

```
2019-03-27T01:20:00
```

Also make sure all other fields have valid values to fix your problem.