# Jquery ajax post sends null when object fields are set with jquery .val() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, http-post

I am using Asp.Net Core MVC. I am trying to post an object to action result using jquery http post. When I set my object with static values, i can see all fields are set properly on client side and backend. Posted object is not null.

When I set fields of request with jquery **.val()** method. Request object is sent as null to backend. Where am I making mistake ?

```
 $("#saveReport").on("click", function () { //SENDS NULL OBJECT
        var request = { 
            BookId: $("#cmbBook").val(),
            PageCount: $("#txtPageCount").val(),
            Date: $("#dateReport").val(),
            Note: $("#txtNotes").val(),
        };

        //var request = { //SENDS OBJECT PROPERLY
        //    BookId: 1,
        //    PageCount: 10,
        //    Note: "test"
        //};

          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: appUrl + "Report/AddUserReport",
                data: JSON.stringify(request),
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function (data) {

                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            });


    });
```

And below is backend

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<ReadingLogResponse> AddUserReport([FromBody]AddReportModel model)
    {
        var response = _reportBusiness.AddReport(new AddReadingLogRequest()
        {
            BookId = model.BookId,
            Date = model.Date,
            Note = model.Note,
            PageCount = model.PageCount
        });

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming that $("#cmbBook") and others are input fields.  Are you setting the values/filling out the fields before clicking on the saveReport button?

Comment: yes, I set input values before clicking the saveReport button. I can see all values are set properly on chrome dev tools.

Comment: please show the html for your inputs

Comment: Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408503/complex-object-is-coming-as-null-for-httpput-in-asp-net-core-2-2/55408989#55408989)

Comment: yes your answer is helpful for me. Thank you. But the main problem is about .net core api configuration. I checked your answer as correct but i may change it if i find solution for api. It would be complete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery .val() method would set the data with string type by default.You need to parse Int.Here is a simple demo like below:

1.Model:

```
public class AddReportModel
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

2.View:

```
<form>
    BookID:<input id="cmbBook" type="text" />
    PageCount:<input id="txtPageCount" type="text" />
    Date:<input id="dateReport"  />
    Notes:<input id="txtNotes" type="text" />
    <input type="button" id="saveReport" value="post" />
</form>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $("#saveReport").on("click", function () { //SENDS NULL OBJECT
            var request = {
                BookId: parseInt($("#cmbBook").val()),
               PageCount: parseInt($("#txtPageCount").val()),
               Date: $("#dateReport").val(),
               Note: $("#txtNotes").val(),
            };
            console.log(request);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(request));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: appUrl + "Report/AddUserReport",
                data: JSON.stringify(request),
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function (data) {
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

3.Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<ReadingLogResponse> AddUserReport([FromBody]AddReportModel model)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: You don't need to parse integers in js to because all values will be serialzied to string by `JSON.stringify` anyways